# Extract JSONArray from JSONObject which does not contain double quote

Tags: java, json, poloniex

I want to extract JSONArray from JSONObject which does not contain double quote.

HTTP response entity as follows.

`{"asks":[["107.47649000",25.3039]],"bids":[["107.06385000",64.9317]],"isFrozen":"0","seq":298458396}`

In specific I need to extract both 107.4764900 and 25.3039.
However, the value 25.3039 does not contain double quote.

my codes are below

```
    public static void bid_ask () throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String queryArgs = "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnOrderBook&currencyPair=USDT_ETH&depth=1";
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(queryArgs);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
    HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
    System.out.println("Poloniex ETHUSDT");
    //System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());


    if (responseEntity != null) {
        try (InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent()) {
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
             String line;

             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(line);
                JSONArray tokenListBid = jsonObj.getJSONArray("bids");
                JSONArray tokenListAsk = jsonObj.getJSONArray("asks");
                JSONArray bid_element;
                JSONArray ask_element;
                double bid[] = new double[2];
                double ask[] = new double[2];

               System.out.println("Poloniex Bid");
                if (tokenListBid != null) { 
                   for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
                      bid_element = tokenListBid.getJSONArray(i);
                      bid[i]=bid_element.getBigDecimal(i).doubleValue();
                      System.out.println(bid[i]);
                   } 
                }


             } //end while()
        }
    }
```

the result shows like this

Poloniex Bid
107.06385

Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[1] not found.

thanks.

Comment: It's not that one of the values isn't double-quoted per se, it's that the one that is quoted is a string, and the other a numeric value.  These cannot be mixed within one and the same array.

Comment: thanks George. so how can i extract a numeric value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat the inner array as an array of Object and typecast them as needed.
Here is simplified example of parsing the "asks" part

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(line);
JSONArray asks = jsonObj.getJSONArray("asks").getJSONArray(0);
Double ask = 0.0;
for (Object o : asks) {
    if (o instanceof String){
        ask = Double.valueOf((String)o);
    } else {
        ask = (Double)o;
    }
    //do something with ask
}
```

**Update**
Here is another way to access the data

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(line);
SONArray asks = jsonObj.getJSONArray("asks").getJSONArray(0);

Double price = Double.valueOf(asks.getString(0));
Double qty = Double.valueOf(asks.getDouble(1));

System.out.printf("Ask price: %.6f, quantity %.4f", price, qty);
```

This is the string I used to test my code

```
String json = "{\"asks\":[[\"107.47649000\",25.3039]],\"bids\":[[\"107.06385000\",64.9317]],\"isFrozen\":\"0\",\"seq\":298458396}";
```

and this is the result I got

> Ask price: 107.476490, quantity 25.3039

Comment: no this will not work. I cannot retrieve Qty from the JSONArray since it lacks double quotes.

Comment: @user1349407 There is no field "Qty" in the json response. Please explain what you mean.

Comment: I know there is no "Qty" field. I mean "numeric values" which not contain double quotes. like 64.9317

Comment: @user1349407 But my answer do handle this in the `else` clause. Did you even try my answer before down voting?

Comment: @user1349407 How does it not work, I am testing this on the string you supplied in the question and it works for me. If you want help you need to be more clear about what your issue is.

Answer (score -1):

`[["107.06385000",64.9317]]` is a `1*2` array, `tokenListBid` is refering to it. So you cann't use `tokenListBid.getJSONArray(1);` to index it.

Comment: I am not sure. same codes in binance API works correctly